Power BI: Custom connector and refresh in power bi services
I'm facing an issue with Power BI desktop, someone from my team developped a custom connector. It is working perfectly on my laptop. So according to Microsoft documentation, I deployed it on the server; on which the gateway is installed.
But when I try to create a new connection in the gateway, it returns the following error message
Unable to create connection for the following reason:
Unable to connect the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection time out occured or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.
Details:
Test-GateWay: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical.
So according to some reading, I installed power BI desktop on the server (on which the gateway is running) and try to use the custom connector, it is also working perfectly.
So during the creation of the gateway, I select skip the connection test (the custom connector connection is set to anonymous) and I try to refresh the dataset, and the following message is returned:
Data source error:    {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"We cannot convert the value null to type Logical."}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Expression.Error"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: Query1.
Any idea of what I could do to try to debug this custom connector?
Many thanks in advance for your help :)
